# How to pass a twodimentional array as argument to a function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
import java.io.*
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val sc = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var grid = Array(9, {IntArray(9)})
    for(i in 0..grid.size - 1) {
        var rowArray = IntArray(9)
        for(j in 0..rowArray.size - 1) {
            rowArray[j] = sc.nextInt()
        }
        grid[i] = rowArray
    }
    for(row in grid) {
        for(j in row) {
            print(j)
            print(" ")
        }
        println("")
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, format your code

Comment: You need to provide a question. What's the error you are observing?

Comment: How did they manage to create a question with only code? When I ask questions which contain a lot of code, StackOverflow starts to complain about it.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass two dimentional array like this:

```
fun test(){
    var arr: Array<Array<String>> = arrayOf(arrayOf("a","b"),arrayOf("1","2"))
    twoDimenArgTest(arr)
}

fun twoDimenArgTest(arr: Array<Array<String>>){
    arr.forEach { it.forEach { println(it) } }
}
```

If this answer is not complete you should specify error like  **s1m0nw1**  suggested.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the two dimensional array just pass the object of grid like

```
twoDimensionalRx(grid)
```

and to receive just receive var with type Array< IntArray > like

```
  fun twoDimensionalRx(a:Array<IntArray>){
    ...
  }
```